# Apply not returning the return value

Tags: javascript, object

I am currently testing the method of javascript functions. When I use the following code:

```
var obj = {
 "name" : "alice",
  "test" : function(){return this.name}
}

obj.test()
> "alice"
```

everything works as expected, but when I do the same with the apply method I get the following:

```
obj.test.apply(this,[])
> ""
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: I dont understand the point of doing this? why not directly access the name. obj.name? Just curious

Comment: The `this` in `obj.test.apply(this,[])` refers to the `window` object. If you do `window.name = 'bob` in the console and then run `obj.test.apply(this,[])` you'll get `bob` in return.

Comment: I am building a system where it is possible to remotely call procedures. This is actually more a proof of concept, I want to be able to use methods that use properties of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass obj as the reference. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4pX/)

```
var obj = {
 "name" : "alice",
  "test" : function() {
      return this.name
  }
}

console.log(obj.test.apply(obj,[]));
```

Similarly if you need to simulate 'call' then

```
var obj = {
 "name" : "alice",
  "test" : function() {
      return this.name
  }
}

console.log(obj.test.call(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

apply() changing context
probably value that you are passing as **this** probably is Window object
imagine you're calling Window.name

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured it out.

The test method should be evaluated not in the global environment, but in the local environment of the object itself. Only then, the this variable is bounded correctly and the name property can be accessed. So I actually have to call

```
obj.test.apply(obj,[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing **this** inside apply and here **this** refers to window and window don't have test method. This will work since you are passing obj which has name method obj.test.apply(obj). Don't get confuse with **obj.test**, it just means you are calling obj's test method but not in obj's context.